# Python requests exception - does this mean the request timed out or that the internet connection of my machine dropped?

Tags: python, python-requests

I suspected that an endpoint I have times out every so often, so I created a python script that sends a request on loop every 30 seconds and prints the responses it receives:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0
    while True:
        res = requests.post(url, payload)

        try:
            response = res.json()
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            response = res.text
        print(response)
        if res.status_code != 201:
            break
        time.sleep(30)
    print(res)
    print(dir(res))
    print(res.status_code)
    print(response)
```

The script eventually failed with the following traceback:

```
{'success': True, 'created_on': '2022-09-08 22:42'} # --- 201 response
{'success': True, 'created_on': '2022-09-08 22:43'} # --- 201 response
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5485BB9A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /new_lead/5kbLWVNXHQ3U6lJ9trME8hPSf (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5485BB9A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\dev\pythonProject\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    res = requests.post(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /new_lead/5kbLWVNXHQ3U6lJ9trME8hPSf (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5485BB9A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

but now I'm a bit confused as to what this means.  If it was the server timing out, wouldn't it give a 500 response and the script would have broke out of the while loop and tried to print the response objects?   Does this mean that my internet connection dropped and the script was unable to make the request because the pc wasn't connected to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first traceback:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

your DNS lookup failed. While that exception was being handled, all the other stuff failed, but that's the underlying problem.

Comment: thanks so it is indicative that the server was down, rather than my own machine?

Comment: No, it's indicative that an attempt was made to query DNS for information about the remote server and that query failed. DNS is separate from the host you're trying to reach